# Why this Dump fail on import?

Tags: mysql

This is my table with data :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(1, 'K-Bal Sound System', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(2, 'Network23 Mixtapes', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(3, 'Artskorps Webmix', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(4, 'GTW Users Mixes', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(5, 'Underground Music Tapes', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(6, 'UK Main Events', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES(7, 'Gabba Nation, Bunker & Box, German Events', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

When I try to import this (with HeidiSql 6.0) I get this error :

```
/* SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry '1' for key 1 */
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table `categories` has to exist and there already is data.

Remove `categories` table before executing that script.

Comment: Would the line: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories`" not take care of that?

Comment: No - it just creates table if there is not already created. If table exists, it skips that part. So that table has data with key `1` and following lines tries to insert again row with key `1`. Table has to be removed/truncated before.

Comment: Yeh sorry I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

if you set `auto_increment` on primary key, remove the `id` in `INSERT` statements

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `user`, `date`) VALUES('K-Bal Sound System', 'djfonplaz', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
...
```

Comment: It is not exact dump of database then - row with key `1` can be now a row with key `34`. During access to that row by id we will get something else than expected.

Comment: So, reset the counter first: ALTER TABLE categories AUTO_INCREMENT= 0.

Comment: Data in table will still exists. When `markzzz` inserts data with specified `id`s it will ignores `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: if data exists in table my first answer works well, if doesn't exists and you need the first id = 1, you have to reset the counter...

Comment: Sure but there is one thing you have to remember. If you dump database and execute that script somewhere else you expect exacly the same scructure with the same data as an oryginal database. With your solution it will not happen. For example missmatch of `FK`s, etc.

Comment: if i dump the database and execute the script somewhere else normally  i don't get any error... but this is not the case...

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a value for your auto increment field. MySQL will automatically insert a value into that field for you so you do not have to try set the value yourself. As it tries to insert your first row it will try to input 1 over the auto increment's value 1.

To fix just remove the id column from your insert.

Comment: It is not exact dump of database then - row with key 1 can be now a row with key 34. During access to that row by id we will get something else than expected.

Comment: This is only 10 lines of code of 25000. I export it with phpMyAdmin interface : what can I do so?

Comment: As I said in my answer - you have to remove all existing tables before executing your script.

Comment: I see what you are saying sorry for the mix up. Yeh hsz is right you need to delete the table if it exists.